# How to resolve Tidyverse 2.0.0 knit to pdf error?

Tags: error-handling, unicode, latex, tidyverse, pdflatex

When I use the tidyverse package knitting to pdf is impossible. I checked this by creating a new Rmd file and knitting to pdf : succesfull. When I just add library(tidyverse) the execution is halted.

! LaTeX Error: Unicode character ^^[ (U+001B)
not set up for use with LaTeX.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile testuh.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See testuh.log for more info.
Execution halted.

I tried reinstalling and almost gave up hope so thanks in advance for every possible solution:)

- deleted and reinstalled tidyverse package
- reinstalled Rstudio

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Problem is resolved by not using library(tidyverse), but only the tidyverse packages used for that script e.g. library(dplyr), library(tidyr)